# "I ___ want to straighten your cap." - only, just, merely, ...?

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

Somebody is wearing a cap. I am stretching out my hand towards the cap. The person is backing away. Probably assuming I would grab the cap. But I don't want to grab the cap. I want to straighten it. So, I am saying:

> I ___ want to straighten your cap.

Which word to use before "want": only, just, merely, ...?

Comment: Why do you think any of those are good choices? Why do you think that they mean different things?

Comment: @mathewb I don't know if any of those are good choices. That's the question. And that's why "..." before the question mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use only, just or merely (though merely is bit formal here). I this context "only" and "just" are synonyms.